# Why would someone want a 58mm-58mm filter ring?

Tags: filters, filter-diameter

I don't even know what to call this thing. It's been sitting in a box of camera stuff for a while and I have forgotten where it came from.[image]

Comment: Can't tell, is there glass in there? Is it the same thread on both sides or is it reversed on one? It could be a reversing ring to mount a lens backwards for macro photography.

Comment: There is no glass, and the threads go the same direction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks like a [spacer ring](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001G470DE), which is used to add space between a lens and a filter (such as close-up filter) or other lens attachment to assist in focusing adjustment or increasing the angle of view.

Note, however, that using this could create some vignetting, especially on wide-angle lenses.